# I am setting the productsList element to null but the products are still being rendered

Tags: reactjs, jsx

On the first render i am setting the productsList with all the products in my redux state. When i click to render products corresponding to a specific category, i am able to set a jsx element (filteredProducts). I have printed it in the console as well but the complete list of products is still being rendered.
I also tried setting the productsList to null, but it is not working as well.

```
const AllProducts = props => {
    
    let productsList = <p>Products are loading. Please wait.</p>;
    let filteredProducts = null;
    let filtered = null

    useEffect(() => {
        props.onFetchProduct();
    },[]);


    const onCategorySelectClicked = (categoryName) => {
        filtered = props.products.filter(product => product.category === categoryName);
        productsList = null;
        // filteredProducts = filtered.map(product => (
        //     <ProductCard 
        //         productName={product.productName}
        //         retailPrice={product.mrp}
        //         newPrice={product.onlinedailymarketPrice}
        //         quantity={product.unitQuantity}
        //         productBarCode={product.id}
        //         key={product.id}
        //     />
        // ))
        // filteredProducts = <p>Products are loaded.</p>;
        console.log(productsList);
    }
     
    let categoryOptions = null;

    if(props.error!==null){
        productsList = <p>{props.error}</p>;
    }
    if(props.fetched){
        productsList = props.products.map(product => (
            <ProductCard 
                productName={product.productName}
                retailPrice={product.mrp}
                newPrice={product.onlinedailymarketPrice}
                quantity={product.unitQuantity}
                productBarCode={product.id}
                key={product.id}
            />
        ))
        console.log(productsList);

        categoryOptions = props.categories.map(category => (
            <div>
                <CategorySelection
                    categoryName={category}
                    clicked={() => onCategorySelectClicked(category)}
                />
            </div>
        ))        
    }

    return (
        <div className={classes.AllProductsHolder}>
            <div>
                {categoryOptions}
            </div>

            {/* {productsList!==null ? productsList : null} */}
            {/* {filteredProducts} */}
            {productsList}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Once this `if(props.fetched)` condition is true the product will render and you are doing that in parent component I guess. Your `productsList ` is getting overwritten below.

Comment: It is not getting overwritten in the if(props.fetched) condition as i have a console.log() statement inside it. I am not getting any console message from it. I am able to set the productsList to null. Printing it in the console as well, but the products are still being rendered.

Comment: If you share your code with parent component, it will help

Comment: To rerender your component when something changes you'll have to use state. Please read the following: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: Suppose i do something like ```const [productName, setProductName] = useState('All Products');  return (<div> {productName === 'All Product' ? productList : filteredProducts } </div>);```

Comment: And then i set the productName on some button click action, will the jsx change if i change the jsx element on the button click function